# Jquery Accordion function, alter class of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion table which is working fine. The glyphicon indicates which tablerows children-row is currently expanded. But something with the function seems to be wrong it doesn't change the class of the ancestor element as expected.

```
$('.accordion-text').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
$(this).closest(".indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
});

$('.accordion-text').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
$(this).closest(".indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/7pwg1j5f/616/

```
<tbody>
        <tr id="package1" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#OrderPackages" data-target=".packageDetails1">
            <td>123456</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="accordion-text accordion-body collapse packageDetails1" id="">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Revealed item 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Revealed item 2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: you can make the arrow change only by css if you want don't need that js code at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you were finding your `.indicator` element was not proper. It resides in the previous `tr` of `.accordion` elements parent `tr`. Just follow the structure and you will get the proper element. Also, you can combine both the events and use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` and `removeClass`. So below is the updated solution.

```
$('.accordion1').on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').prev(".accordion-toggle").find('.indicator').toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
```

> `.closest('tr')` - fetches the parent of `.accordion1` `div`.
>
> `.prev('.accordion-toggle')` - fetches the previous sibling of the
>   earlier obtained `parent`.
>
> `.find('.indicator')` - find the `.indicator` element.
>
> `.toggleClass` - toggles [add/removes] respective class.

## [Here is the Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7pwg1j5f/618/)

**Also note that I've made some changes in html to match the class**

Comment: Perfect! :) Thanks

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your parents selector will never pickup cells from the previous row, you should select row, switch to previous and then find relevant element under that row:

```
$('.accordion1').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parentsUntil("tbody").prev().find(".indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
$('.accordion1').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parentsUntil("tbody").prev().find(".indicator").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```